# "'tag' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of" in a Django app

Tags: django, tags

I added my simple tags to my file in template tags. My first tag is visible and it works properly, but the second one does not work. I receive information `''deposit_earn' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:'` after I added tags to my template `{% load deposit_earn %}`.

My tag file looks like this:

```
@register.simple_tag()
def multiply(number_instalment_loans, rrso, balance):
    rrso_percent = rrso/100
    return round(discounted_interest_rate(12, number_instalment_loans, rrso_percent, balance))

@register.simple_tag()
def deposit_earn(period, interest, balance):
    interest_percent = interest/100
    equals = balance * interest_percent * period / 12
    return round(equals)
```

Why is my first tag working and not the second one? I tried to reset the server after registering the tags, but it did not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

you should import templatetags file name, not method name

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        poll_extras.py
    views.py
```

let say multiply and deposit_earn inside of poll_extras.py

then in your template, you just need call poll_extras

```
{% load poll_extras %}

{{ something|multiply }}
or
{{ something|deposit_earn }}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I also needed to remember to add the app which contained the template tag to INSTALLED_APPS. In case that helps anyone.

Answer (score 4):

You might wanna restart the server after following all the jizz given [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)... It really made me spend about 10 minutes trying to figure out what the problem was when all I had to do was restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

It worths mentioning that, if the `templatetags` directory doesn't exist, after creating it and don't forget to include the empty `__init__.py` script so the directory will be treated as Python package. Otherwise you still get Django error page.